# Magento 2: Maintain Database Changes on Git Versioning

Tags: magento2, database, migration, git, version

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.2.

As we are multiple users are working on Same Project. We have Main Copy of Code + DB on Our Server.

We have done `git clone <repository url>` so everybody has local copy of Code + Database Individually.

The code will manageable. What about database modifications? Everybody is working on different Module & they have coreDB Table changes also.

For custom module will be managable using `InstallSchema.php`, `UpgradeSchema.php`.

What about Magento Core Tables Example: `core_config_data`,`customer_entity`, etc.

How to manage Versioning of that & Upload Changes with File as well.

Have already gone through http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Comment: Why can't everyone work on the same database? I think you're going to have issues with that. The only way to manage it might be to diff all the sqldumps but that will kind of be a nightmare.

Comment: HI @SteveJohnson Initial idea was that. To connect Dev. Server DB from Local, but our Server Provider not providing that facility, means we are not able to connect from Local to Server